# How do you definitely positiont the UI widget?

Tags: android, android-layout

My ios work mate asked the UI designer to give him all the definitely positions of UI widgets, such as margins and size, all in "pixel". And then, the designer also gives me a pic contains all the definitely accurate position information, also in "pixel".

Obviously, my ios work mate designs the UI to be a layout seems like `AbsolutLayout`, which should have been [deprecated since API 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html).

Usually, I use `dp` as margin unit, which is recommended by [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) and works fine. However, it is really a trouble to set different xml document for different screens.

To display what the UI designer designs, I should try:
1. convert px to dp and consider different dps and take different screens in consider.
2. just use `android:layout_weight` of `LinearLayout` to fake a view. However, `LinearLayout` is not recommended by Google. [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

So, how do you definitely position the UI widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , As you said LinearLayout is not recommended by Google- it is not the thing. you should understand the uses of different layouts. they all are good in different diffent scenerio.

Second you need to convert px in dp by using `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

you should not use dp with a high value. generally it is good upto 50 dp (in case of ImageView) but this is not mentioned by any google developers anywhere.

there are different layout which are very useful for designing a screen. Linear layout (with weight , without weight) relative layout, grid layout, table layout all are good, but the thing is you should understand its uses.

The definite measurement can be very useful for margins and padding and some times for height and width if value is not very large.

Comment: Thank U for reply. I have been thinking about the question for a long time. Maybe, it is not important which layout I use. If I can represent the ui design using linear layout with weight, I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

With that you can set Views wherever you want, by aligning them to the parent or other views (top, bottom, left and right) and setting the view's layout_margin[|top|bottom|left|right] as you need.

Also, if you use the layout XML's remember that you don't need to convert between px and dps just by putting tha value as `layout_marginRight="5dp"` will work.

Comment: Thank U for reply. Seems the relative layout is preferred. Usually, I use 5dp as the margin setting. however, a fixed margin is not suitable for all the screens.